# Ionic $timeout not working on phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, timeout

I have a very simple controller that has just few functions for now. It's a temporary solution, but I need to get it to work for now.
It has a $timeout directive called ***timer*** that calls the ***stateForward*** function in 3 seconds, which then cancels the timer, forwards to the next view and clears the cache:

```
$scope.stateForward = function(){
    if ($scope.navigateBool) {
        $timeout.cancel($scope.timer);
        $state.go('app.newtView');
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    }
};


$scope.timer = $timeout(
    $scope.stateForward,
    3000
);
```

It works fine in browsers, but when I compile it to IOS or Android the view is just stuck and nothing happens.

Comment: On which devices are you testing? Are you developing on a Windows or OSX machine? You can actually test your code very easy on your device, with the developer tools of Chrome (Android devices) or Safari (OSx devices).

Comment: where u call "$scope.timer" function ?

Comment: @mhx Developing on Linux (Fedora 22). I'm testing it already on real devices (Samsung S3 mini and iPhone 5S), that's not a problem. Problem is that the $timeout works in browser (Chrome, Mozilla, Safari), but not on the phone.

Comment: Ok, that's good news. Are you familiar with Developer tools? Because it's possible to 'inspect element' live on a connected Android device, when it's connected through Google Chrome. Just open up your console and check if there are any errors. You could even add some breakpoints so you can go through your code, step by step. 

Check this link for more info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

If you can, could you post the error you're getting? (I'm almost sure there must be one) So we can find a solution.

Comment: @maleeb Yeah, actually I guess there is no need to repeatedly call the timer function because it should be instantiated after in 3 seconds after it is set. 
I already put it like this: 
`$timeout(
         $scope.stateForward,
        3000`
and it didn't worked on the phone as well, but it works both ways inside the browser.

Comment: @mhx Thanks a lot for the tip, the Chrome debugger is a great tool. I figured it out, it was throwing the **ReferenceError: $ is not defined** error because in the next view I was missing a JS library, so it wasn't going through to the next view and instead it was stucked on the current view.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was throwing the **ReferenceError: $ is not defined** error because in the next view it was missing a Javascript library, so it wasn't going through to the next view and instead it was stuck on the current view.

So the $timeout works fine, the problem appears when the app is built. The library isn't included inside the apk file, but that's an another issue.